Go back to "non branch commit"
I was trying out Magit on Spacemacs and wanted to push one of my commits to remote, but I realized I had never actually selected a branch after cloning the repository. When I went into one of the branches I realised I had no way to get back to the commit I just made. I did make a commit but it was not tied to any branch it seems, since I can't find the commit on any of the [b b] branches. Does anyone know how I can get back to the commit? Would be a shame to lose the work I just made to the void, tried finding a log file for it but no results there either since everything is tied to branches.

Just as with any other git client, use the git reflog.
